# ¿Como ejecuto un comando de curl usando ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

buenas, me gustaría saber como ejecuto el siguiente comando de curl pero usando ajax

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
  -d amount=1099 \
  -d currency=usd \
  -d "metadata[integration_check]"=accept_a_payment
```

Comment: Si operas con jQuery, cuenta con un método llamado [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), y si intentas hacerlo solo con JavaScript, puedes hacerlo con [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch), si no entiendes alguna cosa, añade lo que hayas intentado y estaré dispuesto a redactar una explicación para aclarar el asunto

Comment: vale, la duda está en cómo mandar esos datos usando ajax, ejemplo, si tuviera un -h xx, sabria que se coloca en headers: xx, pero no sé donde se colocan el -u y el -d en el ajax

Comment: [Lo que encontré](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737031/curlss-option-u) en el sitio en inglés, fue que se puede hacer `usuario:contraseña@sitio.com`

Comment: en que parte se coloca eso ?

Comment: En la URL de la petición, es decir en vez de colocar `http://ejemplo.com` sería `http://usuario:contraseña@ejemplo.com`

Comment: y donde coloco la información que está en -u y en -d ? así como en el ejemplo que publiqué

Comment: El parámetro -u es el ejemplo que te dije, y -d supongo que querrá significar _data_, y también supongo que se envía por el método POST, entonces ya tienes una idea y puedes ir probando

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres replicar las opciones de cURL usando Javascript cuando _Stripe_ tiene un [SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/js) específico?

Comment: porque quiero hacer una prueba de algo muy específico, pero necesito pasar ese código a ajax en javascript

Comment: Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20155531/5587982). Simplemente es cuestión de pasar en el `data` de la petición Ajax los datos que deberá proporcionar el usuario desde el cliente, construyendo tu petición cURL en el archivo .php que pondrías en el parámetro `url`de la petición Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

> No deberías usar estas peticiones del lado del cliente.

Pero basicamente lo que tienes que hacer es esto.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
  },
  data: {amount: 3000, ...}
  ...
})
```

Este es un ejemplo de la libreria en php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código es este...
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/5ebe39d814411594b1ff9d79f0598a0de7faa30b/lib/ApiRequestor.php#L300